# which is faster : firebase-hosting+firebase cloud function OR directly calling a cloud function via HTTP request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I want to understand which of the two below choices I should take. I am optimizing for performance(response time of the API call)

1. I can write a firebase cloud function which will be called when I hit a URL.

   URL : my-custom-domain/webhook
2. Or I can directly call a cloud function directly as a HTTP request. which will be of the form

   URL : https://us-central1-.cloudfunctions.net/date

Doubt : If I use option 1 will I have delayed response time ? I would ideally want to use option 1 because I can give out neat looking URLs to my customers to hit our service. But I don't want to forego performance also.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider where your function is stored and how the hosting on firebase works.

You can decide in what region your function should be. By choosing a region near you it would be reached faster.

The Firebase Hosting works over the the Google Global distribution network. So it could be that your custom url is triggered over that near you but the base of the hosting is always in the USA. Because you have under your URL a function and not just some files that can be cached on that network it will always go to USA.

By playing with those two variants you can make it worse or better. If you take a reagion near you by calling the function by the function URL would be faster than over custom URL.

If you put the function to USA and use custom URL it won't make much difference if you call the custom URL or directly the function.

Then you also need to consider where your databases are at. If they are in a region near you and your function in USA they need to go all the way back near you and so on.

Make a orchestration of region choises for database and functions that would fit your needs.

With the cloud functions never forget the cold start. That makes them very slow on the first use after a while of inactivity.

On the last Google I/O they "anounced" on a QA that they are working on making them stay "hot" but we will be charged for that feature. No one can say when it would come and how much they will charge.